# Foursquare API, app search venues from custom list?

Tags: api, foursquare

I am building an app that has collection of selected dining restaurants. Thus, I think I couldn't use `section` with `https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore` because every restaurants will shown up. And I think I couldn't filter it later too (what if the result contains only not selected restaurants?)

Is there any good solution for this? ... err I am thinking of created new user (may be share name with the app) whose will create the `TODOs` list, then search on this user (instead of app) with option `saved=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if lists will get you anywhere: if you have a discrete list of definitive venues, you could possibly just cache the information on your server and run a search locally without ever going through the Foursquare API. Otherwise, you may want to consider looking into the `categoryId` and `query` endpoints of venues/search (as opposed to explore)